# GWT 2.7.0 StackOverflowError

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

The projects works fine with GWT 2.6.1. Upon changing the version to 2.7.0 I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] Compiling module com.example.gwt.Admin
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:487)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:619)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:508)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:530)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:619)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:508)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:458)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.substitute(Scope.java:421)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CaptureBinding.initializeBounds(CaptureBinding.java:171)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.capture(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:155)
```

(last 2 lines repeating 100s of times)

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Since we can't see your code, I'm not sure how much we can help.

Comment: @RedRoboHood the codebase is way too large to paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like upgrading the asm lib from 4.2 to 5.0.4 has solved the issue, but I'm not sure.